# Set visibility of tab based on workbook file opened on ribbon VSTO Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a VSTO application and in the MainRibbon.xml I am using the getVisible handler to identify whether the tab should be visible or not. The method setVisbility is called in MainRibbon.cs. I am trying to set the visibility of the tab to true if the filename/workbook openend is called "Template.xlsm". Otherwise I dont want to show the below tab.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load" >
  <ribbon >
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="M Template" getVisible="setVisbility" >
        <group id="CreateLoadModel"
               label="Create/Load Model">
          <button id="createmodelbutton" label="Create New Model"
             screentip="Text" onAction="OnCreateModel"
             supertip="Create a new Model"
             imageMso="GroupSmartArtCreateGraphic"/>
        <button id="loadmodelbutton" label="Load Existing Model"
             screentip="Text" onAction="OnLoadModel"
             supertip="Load an Exisitng Model"
             imageMso="FileOpen"/>
        </group>





        public bool setVisbility(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {

        var name = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;

            if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook != null &&
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name == "Template.xlsm")
            {
            return false;
            }

            else
            {
            return true;
            }


    }
```

Everything I currently run the application 'Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name ' is NULL object not defined. This is because the excel application opens without clicking on a file to open. However when i click on the necessary file - it goes back into this setVisibility method but it still states object not defined. How can I set the visibilitty to true/false based on the excel workbook I open?

Comment: Does the problem occur because 'setVisibility' is run when the add-in is loaded? That is, before there is a workbook loaded?

Comment: Yes i think thats why. Not sure how to overcome this. I considered doing it in the workbook open event? But not sure how to change my current logic to get this working in the AddIn.CS

Comment: Please do *NOT* post code as an image, only as plain text. This is an important part of the site guidelines: we cannot copy/paste image content.

Comment: If you see below comment it was just to check the code I have for mine is what should match the person who posted an answer below. Its not there to copy and paste code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occur because `setVisibility` is run before a workbook is loaded. That is `setVisibility` will run when the add-in is loaded.

One solution is to add a check for if any workbook is loaded by using `Workbooks.Count` and then update the visibility everytime a workbook is activated:

```
    public bool setVisbility(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        int nWorkbooks = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Count;
        if (nWorkbooks == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook != null &&
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name == "Template.xlsm")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And then in your ThisAddIn_StartUp method add an eventhandler for activated workbook:

```
this.Application.WorkbookActivate += Application_WorkbookActivate;
```

Then when a workbook is activated force the ribbon to validate like:

```
    private void Application_WorkbookActivate(Workbook Wb)
    {
        RibbonClass.RibbonInstance.Invalidate()
    }
```

Depending on your naming of cource.

Comment: It doesnt recognise RibbonClass? What is this? Where should this method go? "Ribbon Class does not exist in current context"

Comment: Thats the name of your Office.IRibbonExtensibility class. So what ever you have named it. What I have called RibbonInstance is the ribbonUI you create on Ribbon_Load in that class.

Comment: RibbonClass for me is MainRibbon and RibbonInstance for me is ribbon. Is that correct? Added screenshot to original question. If it is im getting an error stating an object reference is required for a non static field , method or property MainRibbon.cs

Comment: Guessing we have to define the Invalidate Method as that does not exist.

     public void Invalidate()
        {
            this.ribbon.Invalidate();
        }

Tried this and now im getting ribbon is NULL

Comment: In your 'public class MainRibbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility' do you have a line like 'internal static Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;' ? Might be the reason you are getting the 'missing non static field' error.

Comment: Ok this seems to be fine. But going back to your answer for setVisibility() this doesnt match what the original question was to see if you can show the tab based on a specific workbook being open. Your suggestion is stating to show the tab if the count of workbooks is not 0? And even if i click on a workbook it still calls this and returns false even though I did select a workbook?

Comment: In the example I have provided, the method returns false, if the count is 0. If not, it does what your originally wanted it to. In debug mode, does it provide a name for the workbook? And how does that match what you expected to see?

Comment: In debug mode it doesnt work - it doesnt provide a name for the workbook. Its coming back as NULL. Even once I have clicked on a workbook. I am getting this error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on the workbook activate method Invalidate()

Comment: I really think I have answered your question. We can't have a long discussion in this thread. You need to put in some effort. A NullRefereneException means you are trying to do something to an object, that's Null. It should be easy to see, which line fails and then troubleshoot from there on. A guess is that you don't reference the Ribbon object correct. Maybe start to check that.

Comment: Debugged and Name is now populating and not NULL and I have now managed to get it working with the help of the answer above!